# NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined when trying to create a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently trying to create a model using transfer learning, but I'm getting an error

```
NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined
```

I'm going to learn from the video. We have loaded some datasets to the computer and I am trying to convert these datasets into '.json' and '.h5' files. I had to run the code you saw in the first part and create the model. There was supposed to be a download like in the video, but instead I got an error and I can't solve it.

Here are my codes:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
from keras.utils import img_to_array
from keras.utils import load_img

train_path = "/Users/atakansever/Desktop/CNNN/fruits-360_dataset/fruits-360/Training/"
test_path = "/Users/atakansever/Desktop/CNNN/fruits-360_dataset/fruits-360/Test/"

# img = load_img(train_path + "Tangelo/0_100.jpg")
# plt.imshow(img)
# plt.axes("off")
# plt.show()

numberOfClass = len(glob(train_path + "/*"))
# print(numberOfClass)

vgg = VGG16()
# print(vgg.summary())

vgg_layer_list = vgg.layers
# print(vgg_layer_list)

model = Sequential()
for i in range(len(vgg_layer_list)-1):
    model.add(vgg_layer_list[i])

# print(model.summary())

for layers in model.layers:
    layers.trainable = False

model.add(Dense(numberOfClass, activation="softmax"))
# print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",optimizer = "rmsprop",metrics = ["accuracy"])

#train
train_data = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(224,224))
test_data = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(224,224))

batch_size = 32

hist = model.fit_generator(train_data,
steps_per_epoch=1600//batch_size,
epochs=25,
validation_data= test_data,
validation_steps=800//batch_size)
```

and here is the error

```
pyenv shell 3.9.7
atakansever@atakan-Air CNNN % pyenv shell 3.9.7
pyenv: shell integration not enabled. Run `pyenv init' for instructions.
atakansever@atakan-Air CNNN % /Users/atakansever/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/bin/python /Users/atakansever/Desktop/CNNN/fruits.py
Metal device set to: Apple M1

systemMemory: 8.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 2.67 GB

2022-07-10 11:17:50.428036: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2022-07-10 11:17:50.428259: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
Found 67692 images belonging to 131 classes.
Found 22688 images belonging to 131 classes.
/Users/atakansever/Desktop/CNNN/fruits.py:53: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  hist = model.fit_generator(train_data, steps_per_epoch=1600//batch_size,epochs=25,validation_data= test_data,validation_steps=800//batch_size)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/atakansever/Desktop/CNNN/fruits.py", line 53, in <module>
    hist = model.fit_generator(train_data, steps_per_epoch=1600//batch_size,epochs=25,validation_data= test_data,validation_steps=800//batch_size)
  File "/Users/atakansever/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2260, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
  File "/Users/atakansever/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/atakansever/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 2244, in apply_affine_transform
    if scipy is None:
NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined
```

Comment: Which versions of Keras and keras_preprocessing do you have?\

Answer (score 4):

try `pip install scipy` or `pip3 install scipy` would solve the problem

Comment: I installed the scipy package but I still get the same error

Comment: DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.25.0,>=1.17.3 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scipy) (1.22.4)

Answer (score 1):

I clicked on the error message and it directed you to the source code.
Comment that two line and save the python script.

```
# if scipy is None:   
#   raise ImportError('Image transformations require SciPy. '   
#                     'Install SciPy.')
```

[Commect code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pjtw.jpg) 
Then it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. Install scipy  `pip install scipy`
2. Restart VS code to your IDE or perhaps restart Python Kernel and rerun the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, install the scipy package if it isn't already installed:

```bash
pip install scipy
```

and then add scipy to your imports:

```py
import scipy # This is new!
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
# ... all your imports
```

Comment: I installed the package but I can't import the scipy package in the import section

Comment: @AtakanSever please show new code and error. Have you olny 1 Python version installed on your computer ? If you have several version things can be a bit complicated as you have to install scipy for the right python version and environment

Comment: I am using python 3.9.7(pyenv). I can use my keras and tensorflow libraries in this version.

Comment: hata kodu `   import scipy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`

Comment: atakansever@atakan-Air CNNN % pip install scipy
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.25.0,>=1.17.3 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scipy) (1.22.4)

Comment: The error message indicates that you have not activated the environment where you wanted to install the library.